# passing a value to a button in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am seeing if there is a way to pass a variable to a button in xcode.  I have a web link that I am retrieving from an API that I am storing to a NSString.  I am just wondering if there is a way to pass that to a button so that when it is clicked it can follow the link accordingly.

Comment: How would I go about storing the index into a tag.  I am unfamiliar with how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store that URL lcoally in some ivar or property. You assign an action to your button as usual. The action is nothing less than a method of your view controller. Within that method you execute that link.

This is how you can "follow" your link:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.klecker.de"]];
```

In your case you would use an NSString variable instead of the constant that I am using in this example.

Comment: I store it locally and I am getting the error use of undeclared indentifier.

Comment: In that case you have not declared that identifier properly. In most cases, nealy all, the compiler tells the truth.

Answer (score 0):

You can just subclass the UIBUtton and add any properties/variables that you like/need. From your description I would use a NSURL instead of NSString...

Create a new UIButton subclass, in your .h file write:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyButton : UIButton
{
     NSURL* buttonUrl;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL* buttonUrl;
@end
```

and in the .m file simply:

```
#import "MyButton.h"
@implementation MyButton
@synthesize buttonUrl;
@end
```

Then in your ViewController:  (don't forget to #import "MyButton.h)

```
MyButton *theButton = [[MyButton alloc] initWithFrame:someframe];
[theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPushed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
theButton.buttonUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:apiString];
[self.view addSubView:theButton];
[theButton release];
```

... And then you can get the URL again when the button was pushed as:

```
-(void)buttonPushed:(id)sender{
    NSURL* theUrl = [(MyButton*)sender getButtonUrl];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very descriptive answer.  Where would I play the MyButton *theButton portion of the code at? In the viewDidLoad?

Comment: Np. Where you should place it depends a lot on your application. If you want to use exactly what I wrote above you should put it whenever you get your "api string". But this is only if you assign and load the api string only once. If you need to keep track of the button itself and update the assigned api string/url, you should define your MyButton object in .h file, alloc and init it in for example viewDidLoad and then release it in dealloc.

Comment: This is the wrong approach. The button shouldn't store the URL, this is the job of the view controller as stated in the other answer.

Comment: Wow. Yes, subclassing is clearly an option. However, I guess for this job it is a bit overdone. The regular classes of UIViewController and UIButton provide all you need for this task.